# java: Object1 & Object2 same as Object2 & Object1

Tags: java, unique, hashcode

I try to draw lines between different GridPositions(x,y). Every GridPos has 4 Connections North, East, South, West. The Problem is if I paint a line from GridPos(1,1) to GridPos(2,2) the program will paint also a line in reverse direction between GridPos(2,2) and GridPos(1,1) later.

I tried to solve the problem with this class (WarpGate is the same as GridPos):

```
public class GateConnection {

private WarpGate gate1 = null;
private WarpGate gate2 = null;

public GateConnection(WarpGate gate1, WarpGate gate2) {
    super();
    this.gate1 = gate1;
    this.gate2 = gate2;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;

    int result = prime * ((gate1 == null) ? 0 : gate1.hashCode());
    result += prime * ((gate2 == null) ? 0 : gate2.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    GateConnection other = (GateConnection) obj;
    if ((gate1.equals(other.gate1) || gate1.equals(other.gate2)) && (gate2.equals(other.gate2) || gate2.equals(other.gate1))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

This Class could be added to an HashSet and the double painting would be gone but I don't know if the hashValue is always unique.

HashCode of WarpGate (auto-generated by eclipse):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + gridX;
    result = prime * result + gridY;
    return result;
}
```

For now I use an ArrayList. I look if the GateConnection exists, if not then add. But this version takes much more ressources than using a HashSet.

**EDIT:**

The white rectangles are the connections which are painted, the numbers are the GridPositions(x|y) and the red Arrows are the two directions the rectangle is painted because GridPos(2|2) has a connection to GridPos(4|2) and (4|2) to (2|2)
[image]

Comment: Adding a picture of your problem may be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TreeSet` neither uses `hashCode()` nor `equals()`. It uses `compareTo()`, though you should ensure it is consistent with `equals()` to respect `Set` semantics.

For a `HashSet`, the `hashCode()` of a stored object does *not* have to be unique. In fact, you can return the same code for every item if you want and they will still be stored without losing any items, if your `equals()` is implemented correctly. A good `hashCode()` will improve performance only.

**The only critical rule is that two equal items must generate the same hash code.**

Your implementation looks OK as long as you can guarantee that `gate1` and `gate2` are never equal within the same `GateConnection` object. If they are equal, two `GateConnection` objects could have different hash codes but be reported as equal. That would lead to unpredictable behaviour if they are stored in a `HashSet`.

E.g. GateConnection((1,1), (1,1)) *equals* GateConnection((1,1), (7,9)) but the hash codes are different.

Comment: I think I had a false thought about HashSet. I was thinking if you add something to  the Set and the hash is already there it will be overwritten...

Comment: Yeah, it's a common misconception.